# Black stripes at the junctions of road segments

Tags: unity, c#

I made a simple runner where the road is dynamically generated, and the sphere together with the camera moves with the help of Rigidbody velocity, but the problem is that black bars appear at the joints between segments, and if you add an AddForce sphere, then the sphere at the joints jumps which should not be. How to solve this problem

[image]

I checked the positions of the segments, they fully correspond to the desired ones, that is, there are no gaps between them, I use the standard shader

Segments 10.4 units in size. Imported from Blender, but if you take the standard cube model then the same thing (black bars), so that’s not the point. Positions between these segments:

The segment before (on which the sphere in the screenshot)

[image]

and the next segment

[image]

Road Material Settings:

[image]

Comment: The black bars can be an issue of shadow mapping depth precision. If you tighten the near/far plane on your camera closer to your displayed range, or tweak your shadow distance settings, do you notice any change or improvement?

Comment: @DMGregory And if the shadows are off?

Comment: Then that's doubly reason to suspect depth precision issues, but this time from your camera. What happens if you bring your far plane in as tight as you can without clipping your scene?

Comment: @DMGregory, I was able to set to 20, but that did not help.

Comment: @DMGregory, The problem is solved if Anti Aliasing 8x is turned on, does this change the reason that I can do something to remove the strips without turning on
Anti Aliasing 8x?

Comment: If this is the case then there is probably a tiny gap between the road segments, because of aliasing they appear a stripes between road segments. Enabling anti aliasing makes the stripes far less apparent, but a better solution would be to adjust the generation algorithm to add a very small overlap between the road segments.

Comment: @ThomasMathieson, It did not help

Comment: @DMGregory, I changed the rotation of the camera and it helped

Comment: You don't need to tag me in every update. Just be sure to edit your question so your findings so far are all in one place, and any user who has an answer to share can post it below.